# Displaying Bitmap objects in Crystal Report as Picture Box using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How can I display a Bitmap object in a crystal report viewer without saving it in a new file?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the bitmap byte array from the picture box.

   ```
   PictureBox yourPictureBox;
   using (var mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
     yourPictureBox.Image.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
     byte[] yourByteArray = mStream.ToArray();
   }
   ```
2. Put a column of type byte[] in your dataset.

   ```
   yourDataTable.Columns.Add("YourImageColumn", typeof(byte[]))
   ```
3. Put base64Binary element in your XSD.

   ```
   <xs:element name="Logotipo" type="xs:base64Binary" />
   ```
4. Fill it as base-64 string.

   ```
   yourDataRow["YourImageColumn"] = Convert.FromBase64String(yourByteArray);
   ```
5. In CR designer, put the field (image) wherever you want it.